# WooCommerce: How to check if meta key exists for a specific product

Tags: php, wordpress, function, methods, woocommerce

Situation: modifying the product template to display some HTML only IF a specific product meta exists / is set / greater-than-zero (it's an additional price type, it will either be empty or a positive integer).

The actual meta is the Booster for WooCommerce "MSRP Price", which is added as a meta field.

So this works: `echo do_shortcode( '[wcj_product_meta name="_wcj_msrp"]' );`

But I only want to display it IF the product in question does have an MSRP set (not all the products in the store will). The test for this can be "not empty", "is set", or "greater than zero".

Trying the following syntax:

```
<?php if ($product ->metadata_exists(_wcj_msrp)) {
    echo '<li class="single-product-price price-msrp">MSRP: <span>$</span>';
    echo do_shortcode( '[wcj_product_meta name="_wcj_msrp"]' );
    echo '</li>';
  }
?>
```

Result: page loads endlessly.

What is the simple stupid thing that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

First `metadata_exist()` is a WordPress conditional function, **but not a `WC_Product` method** (or an inherited `WC_Data` method). That's why your code doesn't work, because you are not using [`metadata_exist()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/metadata_exists/) in the right way as the function requires 3 arguments and can't not be used as a method on a `WC_Product` Object.

Assuming that your shortcode works without problems, and that the `WC_Product` Object is defined and accessible. **You have 2 possibilities** to check if a meta key exist for a product *(located in `wp_postmeta` table)*:

1) Using WooCommerce `WC_Data` [`meta_exist()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Data.html#_meta_exists) *(conditional)* method this way:

```
<?php if ( $product->meta_exists( '_wcj_msrp' ) ) {
    echo '<li class="single-product-price price-msrp">MSRP: <span>$</span>';
    echo do_shortcode( '[wcj_product_meta name="_wcj_msrp"]' );
    echo '</li>';
} ?>
```

2) Using [`metadata_exist()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/metadata_exists/) WordPress conditional function this way:

```
<?php if ( metadata_exists( 'post', $product->get_id(), '_wcj_msrp' ) ) {
    echo '<li class="single-product-price price-msrp">MSRP: <span>$</span>';
    echo do_shortcode( '[wcj_product_meta name="_wcj_msrp"]' );
    echo '</li>';
} ?>
```

Both should work.

Comment: Option 1 didn't work - it still outputs "MSRP: $" even if there's no MSRP; this is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Aaannnnd Option 2 didn't work either.

Hm. Maybe my assumption was wrong, and checking for the existence of the metadata field is a bad idea - I should check for whether the field is actually empty or not.

Comment: @TomJones999 I have already user both of them and they work fine… In your case, nobody can test that for you, to see what is wrong. My answer just show you what is the mistake related to `metadata_exists()`  in your code…

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about wordpress,but i took a look and for what i've see that metadata_exists requires the meta type, the object id and meta key. Maybe you should check your implementation on $product ->metadata_exists().

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Thanks, LoicTheAztec, for putting me on the right path! :)

```
<?php $msrp = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_wcj_msrp', true );
  if ($msrp == '') {
    echo '';
  } else {
    echo '<li class="single-product-price price-msrp">MSRP: <span>$ ';
    echo do_shortcode( '[wcj_product_meta name="_wcj_msrp"]' );
    echo '</span></li>';
  }
?>
```

Tested it, works correctly. If there IS a value in the MSRP field, it outputs the LI and its proper contents. If the MSRP field is empty, it outputs nothing.

Life lesson here is: don't check for whether a metadata field exists, because it might exist regardless. Check whether it's empty or not.

Answered, closed, thank you!