# Remove WooCommerce cart quantity selector from cart page only if cart item has specific meta data

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, cart

I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50562872/4952851) which can remove the cart quantity selector as needed, however I only need to do this if a cart item has specific meta data. As I need to check for cart item meta rather than product meta, I can't use answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57650264/4952851).

How can I update the below code to only apply if the item has the cart meta data 'Ticketnumber'?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', 'wc_cart_item_quantity', 10, 3 );
function wc_cart_item_quantity( $product_quantity, $cart_item_key, $cart_item ){
    if( is_cart() ){
        $product_quantity = sprintf( '%2$s <input type="hidden" name="cart[%1$s][qty]" value="%2$s" />', $cart_item_key, $cart_item['quantity'] );
    }
    return $product_quantity;
}
```

I thought I could use some code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58676462/4952851) for retrieving the cart item meta, but I can't figure it out.

```
function kia_add_subtitle_to_cart_product( $title, $cart_item ){
    $_product = $cart_item['data'];
    $meta     = $_product->get_meta( 'product_card_beschrijving', true ); // THIS PART
    if( $meta ) {
        $title .= '<span class="meta">' . $meta . '</span>';
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'kia_add_subtitle_to_cart_product', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$cart_item['data']->get_meta()`

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_cart_item_quantity( $product_quantity, $cart_item_key, $cart_item ) {
    // Get meta
    $ticketnumber = $cart_item['data']->get_meta( 'Ticketnumber', true );   

    if ( $ticketnumber ) {
        $product_quantity = sprintf( '%2$s <input type="hidden" name="cart[%1$s][qty]" value="%2$s" />', $cart_item_key, $cart_item['quantity'] );
    }
    
    return $product_quantity;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', 10, 3 );
```